# Show text as asterisks

Tags: shell-script, output

So, I'm just trying out a simple program. But the thing is i want to change a certain text to asterisk to hide the text, but want the number of asterisks or dots to be the same as number of letters. Here's my code...

```
#! /bin/bash
read -p 'Username:' name
read -sp 'Password:' pass
echo Confirm Username: $name?
echo Confirm Password: $pass?
echo Let us start the quiz :P
echo Q1 - Full form of MCQ
echo a - Maximum Capture Quest
echo b - Multiple Choice Question
read -p "Your Answer:" word
if [[ $word == "b" ]]
then
  echo "Correct! V.Good"
else
  echo "Wrong."
fi
```

So I want this part to be covered: `echo Confirm Password: $pass?`. I'm not saving any data, so I just simply want the text hidden.

Comment: I would argue that you do *not* want the number of asterisks or dots to be the same as the number of letters, since this leaks the number of letters in the password!

Comment: @Celada That's a compromise between vulnerability to shoulder surfing, and unfriendliness which causes users to pick weaker passwords. Leaking the number of letters is usually the a good compromise.

Comment: Actually, i was just messing around trying to make a quiz kind of thing but then my linux teacher game me homework to display the confirm password part as an asterisk

Comment: @Celada If your password is 7+ characters long that really isn't a vulnerability.

Answer (score 2):

So when the user enters the password `blahblah`, you want to show `********`? That's not much of a confirmation, they won't be able to check what they typed.

But, you can do that in by using the string substitution expansion `${var//pattern/replacement}` (In Bash and other shells, not standard POSIX shell):

```
#!/bin/bash
read -sp "Password: " pass
echo
echo "Confirm Password: ${pass//?/*}"
```

The `?` matches any character, `//` tells to replace all matches, so you get all characters changed to asterisks. Note the quotes; without them, the word would be expanded for filenames, and the asterisks match all files in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo "hello there"
hello there

$ echo "hello there" | tr -c \\n \*
***********
```

The need to escape characters will be based on your local setup and will require some trial-and-error.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an exact solutions. But, with bash something similar can be achieved by using [escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). A piece of text can be struck through or completely hidden with relative ease. Just change your confirmation line to the following.

```
echo Confirm Password: ^[[8m$pass^[[0m?
```

This will print each character in the password as a blank space. The 8 can be changed to a 9 for strikethrough instead. Note that the `^[` is not these literal characters, instead it is a special character that can be inserted by pressing ctrl+v then esc.

If it is required to print asterices in place of characters you might be best off defining a function something like the following.

```
function nstars {
    for i in $(seq $1); do
        echo -n '*'
    done
}
```

This function can then be used something like this:

```
echo Confirm Password: $(nstars ${#pass})?
```

It will probably be required to do some extra escaping to avoid the shell using * as a globbing character.

Comment: In Bash you can replace all characters in a string with an asterisk with a simple parameter expansion: `${pass//?/\*}` (you should use double quotes around this value, though! No "extra escaping", just proper quoting).

Comment: Wow, did not know about this syntax. That is vastly better than my hackish solution. I felt dirty even writing it :D .